# Diffrence between "wr" and "copy running config to startup config"

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

For saving configuration in Cisco devices we have "wr" and "copy running config to startup config" i am curious what is difference between these two command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They essentially achieve the same things by saving the running configuration to the memory so that after a reload it retains the same configuration. Write memory is the "ancient" way, and copy running-config startup-config is the "newer way". Some newer platforms do not accept write memory, the Nexus platforms for instance. The workaround is to create an alias using `cli alias name wr copy run start` in global configuration mode.

The "copy run start" command is just a variation of the "copy" command. The copy command can be used to copy any files in or out of the flash etc. - as opposed to just saving the configuration. Just remember though, if you are in the wrong configuration register "wr" will lose your configuration after a reload/when you change the configuration register whereas "copy run start" will just copy the contents of the running configuration to the start-up configuration.

When doing CCNA exams, the command "write" is not allowed.  It has to be the official "copy running-config startup-config".

The reason why the "wr" or "write" command is very popular are:

1. A minimum of two characters to save a config;
2. It is easy to confuse "copy start run" with "copy run start".

Source: https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/difference-between-quot-copy-run-start-quot-and-wr/m-p/2943355

Comment: If the length of copy run start is too long to type out (or tab out) you can abbreviate to `cop r s` and that achieves the same thing.